# Extending a class or Creating a new function, Which is better?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, ecmascript-5

If somebody wants to implement a function (e.g. `Array.prototype.filter`) for an old browser which method is better? Why? What is pros and cons of each one?

```
if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
  Array.prototype.filter = function() {
    //implementation
  }
}
```

or

```
function myFilter(e,i,f) {
    if (!Array.prototype.filter) {
        //implementation
    } else {
        return Array.prototype.filter(e,i,f);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use the first approach (adding `Array.prototype.filter`) most of the time, but there are times when I don't.  I don't use the first approach when writing large-scale frameworks for old browsers, which need to play nice with any other scripts on the internet, including bad ones.

Here are the things to consider.  Let's say you shim in `Array.prototype.filter` using the method you described, and then you add a 3rd party script to your website that does something like this:

```
var someArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];
console.log('The first three letters of the alphabet are: ');
for (var i in someArray)
    console.log(someArray[i]);
```

The result?

```
The first three letters of the alphabet are: 
a
b
c
function () { ... }
```

Your filter function gets printed out! Now, on a technical level, no one should iterate arrays with a `for...in` loop, but you can't control what 3rd party scripts might do. This is the main drawback, and when you're writing a large-scale library to be used all over the internet, it's worth considering.

This prevents you from adding anything to `Object.prototype`, period (with a simple Object.prototype.method = function() { ... }`assignment), because`for...in`is good to use on other types of objects, and this kind of shimming breaks`for...in`.

But, if you're just writing code to be used on your own website, and you know the scripts you'll be including are high quality and don't make blunders like this, it's a fine technique.

In addition, if your code is only intended for ECMAScript 5 compliant browsers, you can define your shims as non-enumerable, which will prevent them from showing up in `for...in` loops. I am currently working on a project to shim in ECMAScript 6 methods to ES5 browsers, and since it's only intended to run in ES5 browsers, I can get away with:

```
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, 'contains', {
    value: function(value) {
        // Implementation
    },
    enumerable: false,
    writable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Defining the shim in this way prevents it from showing up in a `for...in` loop, so it's even safe to use on `Object.prototype`, **provided your implementation accurately follows the spec/draft**.

Which brings up a secondary point. If you are not confident you can accurately implement the method as per the spec, you may also be better off not to shim it in. This could break libraries which check for the built-in and use it if available, but fall back to something else if it's not. Better to leave them without anything than with a broken implementation.

It's for this reason that I never try to partially implement a shim.  For instance, `Object.create` cannot be completely implemented in ES3 browsers, so I don't shim this one in ever. I just use my own `myLibrary.create` function, which may function similarly, but at least any code which may check for the existence of `Object.create` isn't being misled to believe it has a full, working version.

Moral of the story: If you're going to shim, check out some of the really awesome, spec-compliant shims on MDN, and learn to write code like it: [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter#Compatibility)

---

A final note: The reason many libraries don't shim in methods on `Array.prototype` may be in part to some of these considerations, but there's also a historical reason in many of these cases. Libraries like jQuery were being developed *before* `filter` was a standard built-in method. Prototype.js took the approach of *adding* non-standard methods, which has more drawbacks than those discussed above. jQuery decided not to add non-standard methods to the built-in prototypes, and that's why they have `$.filter`.

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is more common; it's used by such popular shim JS libraries as jQuery and Underscore.js.

Said that, extending **native objects** is far less dangerous then extending **host objects** (with latter, it's typical 'catch 22': you extend them to provide additional functionality in browsers that don't handle extending of the host objects well enough). [This article](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/) sums it up:

> Don’t forget that writing proper, compliant shims is hard. When in
>   doubt, use standalone object. When the method you’re shimming is part
>   of the unfinished spec, use standalone object. Only when you’re
>   certain about method compliance and method is part of the finished,
>   future-proof specification, is it safe to shim native object directly.

Comment: This is exactly my question, why jQuery and Underscore think that second approach is better and Prototype selected first approach
What you mean by "... that handle extending native objects not so well."

Comment: I disagree (at least until a more detailed explanation for the issue with older browsers is provided, and if it convinces me). I don't see any problem with shimming native objects, as long as the shim behaves as the standard method. Related reading: http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/

Comment: @bfavaretto You're right, of course. I wrote that answer thinking the question was about host objects (as well), while it's different situtation with native ones. Still, I prefer using "standalone" objects approach, following that "Don't modify objects you don't own" maxima. So far it pays off.

Answer (score 0):

For new standard js function and class best practice is [shiming](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim), extending classes if the function is not found on old browsers.

But if the function does not become standard best practice is creating new function and do not change standard class, because if you use a function name that may be used in future with different behavior it will break your app.